# How to change color of histogram based on specific values in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, histogram

So I have this large data frame, which contains a column named "sentiment", that lists different values like 0,43 or 0,62 and many many more.

This is a minimal example of two entries in the df:

`df <- dataframe(text=c("This is awesome", "I hate it"), sentiment=c("0.62","0.43"))`

I would like to plot a histogram now using `ggplot 2`.

My code looks like this:

```
ggplot(test)+
aes(x=sentiment, y=..density..,fill=sentiment)+
geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.01)+
geom_vline(aes(xintercept=mean(sentiment)),
         color="blue", linetype="dashed", size=0.5)+
geom_density(alpha=.2,col="#FF6666")
```

How do I color all the "sentiment" values under 0.5 in red and all the values above 0.5 in green?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest would be to use `scale_fill_manual` with the `fill` parameter within the `aes()` of `geom_histogram`:

```
ggplot(df)+
  aes(x=sentiment, y=..density..)+
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.01, aes(fill = sentiment < .5)) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=mean(sentiment)),
             color="blue", linetype="dashed", size=0.5)+
  geom_density(alpha=.2,col="#FF6666") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("green", "red"))
```

[image]